# Loading NSMutableArray Into UITableView Crashes On Scroll

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to load my NSMutableArray into a UITableView but it crashes as soon as you scroll.  The data loads into the UITableView but like I said I can't scroll.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize myArray = _myArray;

#pragma mark TableViewStuff

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _myArray.count;
}


//—-insert individual row into the table view—-
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    //—-try to get a reusable cell—-
    UITableViewCell *cell =
    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    //—-create new cell if no reusable cell is available—-
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]
                autorelease];
    }

    //—-set the text to display for the cell—-
    NSString *cellValue = [_myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

    return cell;
}
#pragma mark LifeCycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Load the file into a string
    NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"listOfColleges" ofType:@"txt"];
    NSString* myString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    //Fill the array with subsets of the string
    _myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    [_myArray release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

MyArray is retained and it is non-atomic, so I should be good to go.  Maybe something is dying though before the UITableView can use it?

The error that I am getting is as follows:

EXC_BAD_ACCESS @ this line - `NSString *cellValue = [_myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Comment: You should set the array with `self.myArray = ` so your defined property accessor method gets a chance to run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
_myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]];
```

You are not accessing your setter so the retain isn't happening. You want:

```
self._myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]];
```

or

```
[_myArray release];
_myArray = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]] retain];
```

or

```
[_myArray release];
_myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]];
```